# User.Identity.GetUserName() and GetUserId() return empty strings when post IdentityServer3 authentication

Tags: identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 and would like it so that User.Identity.GetUserName() and User.Identity.GetUserId() return the values stored in the Claims. Right now I see them in the claims as "sub" and "email". Is it possible to either:

1. Make IdentityServer3 return these as Claims? I'm guessing they would be nameidentifier and name.
2. Add the claims once the client app authenticates so that the User.Identity methods are usable.

Hopefully this made some sense and I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I added a new Scope to the Scopes class:

```
new Scope
{
     Name = "public",
     DisplayName = "Public scope",
     Type = ScopeType.Identity,
     IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true
}
```

Then I modified my login url in the SignIn action of the AccountController:

```
var url = Settings.AuthorizeEndpoint +
     "?client_id=" + Settings.ClientId +
     "&response_type=id_token" +
     "&scope=openid email profile public" +
     "&redirect_uri=" + Settings.RedirectUri +
     "&response_mode=form_post" +
     "&state=" + state +
     "&nonce=" + nonce;
```

That seemed to do the trick.